# SearchView crashes when I input a location into it

Tags: java, google-maps, android-layout, searchview

I am creating a searchview for my Google Maps in Android Studio using Java however when I type in a location the emulator crashes I used this [video](https://youtu.be/QnIWzKB4084) and followed it step by step however my app still crashes and gives me the error at com.example.routeplanner.MainActivity$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:77)

Here is my Java Code:

```
IMPORTS
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SearchView searchView;
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentMap);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                if (location == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else
                {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try
                    {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                        if (addressList.size() > 0 )
                        {
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(addressList.get(0).getLatitude(),addressList.get(0).getLongitude());
                            if (marker != null)
                            {
                                marker.remove();
                            }
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location);
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5);
                            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                            marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        }
                    }catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

XML for the searchView is:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#BFBFBF"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search Location" />

I tired doing the searchview another way however this did not work for me either I was using this [video](https://youtu.be/68HWFGCSAj8) But I was getting the same error

These are the errors I am getting: 
"E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.routeplanner, PID: 3893
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.routeplanner.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:115)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzar.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:3)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
        at fj.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230514022@23.05.14 (040700-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230514022@23.05.14 (040700-0):1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)"
```

Comment: Could you add the whole crash log? that would give us a clear idea.

Comment: Just added all the errors that come up for me

Comment: It shows there is a null pointer exception while using getLatitude() method at your MainActivity code line 115. Could you check that line? Or add the whole MainActivity Code including the imports as well